# Will I always get user email when using oauth2 social login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

User can create Facebook account using only phone (without email) so question is what would be send to our backend api in profile data. Will I get auto generated email or something?

Answer (score 0):

No you will not get such email. You have to authenticate through facebook auth and manage other stuff by mobile number.